# how to fetch field from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following

```
   Response Data: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [offer_id] => 1370
            [Thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [48286] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 48286
                            [offer_id] => 1370
                            [display] => gream-2.jpg
                            [filename] => gream-2.jpg
                            [size] => 14014
                            [status] => active
                            [type] => offer thumbnail
                            [width] => 100
                            [height] => 50
                            [code] => 
                            [flash_vars] => 
                            [interface] => network
                            [account_id] => 
                            [is_private] => 0
                            [created] => 2015-02-16 08:28:59
                            [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [url] => http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/1370/gream-2.jpg
                            [thumbnail] => http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/1370/thumbnails_100/gream-2.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And I have populated this array by the following code:

```
  if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
        // No errors encountered
        echo 'API call successful';
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Response Data: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'], true);

        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Now I want to fetch the [url] from the array and to do this here is my effort:

```
foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data'] as $data) {


   echo '<img src="'.$data['id']['url'].'">';   

}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Organize your array with line breaks so we can actually see it.

Comment: @Devon...line breaks in the code? I have no idea how to do this dear

Comment: @Devon...please refer to the array printed here http://megaofferz.com/sc/xml2.php...

Comment: I copied it for you.  Next time use the HTML source or add <pre> in the HTML before the array output.

Comment: @Devon....thanks i will follow ur suggestion next time

Comment: There is no `['id']['url']` in the array.  There is a `['Thumbnail'][48286]['url']`.  So I think you need to analyze your code a little better.   How are you planning on getting the ID then accessing the ID?   It might help you to see better to `print_r($data)` inside the foreach to see what you have available.

Comment: @Devon...should i access the offer_id first?

Comment: You are going to have to do nested loops.  You can do a foreach, then when offer_id = something, do a foreach on Thumbnail, etc..

Comment: @Devon...have tried a lot...could not get ant result...can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this doesn't work, please try to describe more how it's built.

```
foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data'] as $data) {

 $urls = array();
 foreach($data['Thumbnail'] AS $thumbnail){
  array_push($urls, $thumbnail['url']);
 }

 /* All urls if there are several */
 foreach($urls AS $url){
  echo '<img src="'.$url.'">';
 }

 /* Or only first */
 echo '<img src="'.$urls[0].'">';
}
```

[edit]
I can't see why it wouldn't work, do you get any errors? Try to print out step by step; $urls after the foreach, $data['Thumbnail']...

Comment: ...no it didnt work...you can check this url http://megaofferz.com/sc/xml2.php....the array is printed here

Comment: foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data'] as $data) {
    $urls = array();
 foreach($data['Thumbnail']['$url'] AS $thumbnail){
  array_push($urls, $thumbnail['url']);
  
 }
 echo $urls;
} this code prints Array

Comment: You wrote `$data['Thumbnail']['$url']`, it should only be `$data['Thumbnail']` in the `foreach`, so `foreach($data['Thumbnail'] AS $thumbnail)`

Comment: foreach($data['Thumbnail'] AS $thumbnail)
   {
       array_push($urls, $thumbnail['url']);
       
   }
   echo $thumbnail;....it also gives me printed just an Array...

Comment: `echo` won't print out arrays, try `print_r($urls)`. If that doesn't work, `print_r($data)` and compare it with your first array.